# Required if doesn't working when comparing an enum with string in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need a slight help from you. I have a "RequiredIf" which is comparing a value from "EnumDropdown" and a "string" field but the code is not working in Jquery validation. Can anyone please suggest a way to do that.Below are the code snippets.

ViewModel :

```
[RequiredIf("ValidationOption", CustomerParameter.Phone, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Customer_cshtml), ErrorMessageResourceName = "PhoneRequired")]
public string Phone { get; set; }   
[RequiredIf("ValidationOption", CustomerParameter.Account, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Customer_cshtml), ErrorMessageResourceName = "CustomerRequired")]   
public string Account{ get; set; }
public CustomerParameter ValidationOption { get; set; }
```

JQUERY:

```
$.validator.addMethod('requiredif', function (value, element, parameters) {
    var id = '#' + parameters['dependentproperty'];
    var targetvalue = parameters['targetvalue'];
    targetvalue = (targetvalue == null ? '' : targetvalue).toString();
    var control = $(id);
    var controltype = control.attr('type'); --->//This line is getting undefined for EnumDropdownList property
    var actualvalue ;
    if (controltype === 'checkbox') {
        actualvalue = control.is(':checked').toString();
    } else if (controltype === 'radio') {
        actualvalue = $('input[name='+parameters['dependentproperty']+']:checked').val()
    } else {
        actualvalue = control.val();
    }

    // in the following, targetvalue is the name of the property (e.g.Phone or Account)
    // but actual value is the value of selected enums value (e.g. 0 or 1)
    // so the rules are not being added
    if (targetvalue === actualvalue)
        return $.validator.methods.required.call(this, value, element, parameters);
```

Comment: You need to show the view

Comment: And if your using `EnumDropdownList()` then `control.attr('type')` will be `undefined` since its a `<select>` (which does not have a `type` attribute) not an `<input>`